# login/logout problem in project using laravel,inertiajs and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on project using Laravel, inertiajs/inertia-laravel and vuejs.
After login when dashboard is shown and when  try to logout the logout button is not working, to make it work i have to refresh every time then it work fine same goes with login after logout when i try to login again face the same issue. I have to refresh again to login.

in my console this error is shown

```
  Wed Jul 13 11:17:42 2022] 127.0.0.1:52434 Closing
  [Wed Jul 13 11:17:43 2022] 127.0.0.1:52437 Accepted
  [Wed Jul 13 11:17:43 2022] 127.0.0.1:52437 [200]: GET /site.webmanifest
  [Wed Jul 13 11:17:43 2022] 127.0.0.1:52437 Closing
  [Wed Jul 13 11:17:43 2022] 127.0.0.1:52438 Accepted
  [Wed Jul 13 11:17:46 2022] 127.0.0.1:52438 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
```

these are my routes

```
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@store')->name('login.attempt')->middleware('guest');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

```
this is my controller code for login and logout
```

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
    use Inertia\Inertia;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */
    
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    
    
        /**
         * Show login form
         *
         * @return \Inertia\Response
         */
        public function showLoginForm()
        {
            
            // return Inertia::render('Auth/Login');
            return Inertia::render('Auth/Login', [
    
                // ALWAYS included on first visit
                // OPTIONALLY included on partial reloads
                // ALWAYS evaluated
                'users' => User::get(),
            
                // ALWAYS included on first visit
                // OPTIONALLY included on partial reloads
                // ONLY evaluated when needed
                'users' => fn () => User::get(),
            
                // NEVER included on first visit
                // OPTIONALLY included on partial reloads
                // ONLY evaluated when needed
                'users' => Inertia::lazy(fn () => User::get()),
            ]);
        }
    
    
        /**
         * Handle an incoming authentication request.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function store(LoginRequest $request)
        {
            $request->authenticate();
          
            $request->session()->regenerate();
    
            return redirect('/');
        }
    
        
    
        /**
         * Log the user out of the application.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function logout(Request $request)
        {
            
            Auth::guard('web')->logout();
            
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
    
            // $request->session()->invalidate();
    
            // $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    
            // return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```